# Always automatically add/stage/commit specific file on modification

Tags: git

I have a working directory with source code and a resulting file upon compilation.  I do not track intermediate build files, but I would like to keep a working finished product with each change of the source code that I track with `git add` and `git commit`.

It is becoming tedious to add that same resultant file every time I commit and push my work.  Is there a "anti-.gitignore" file I can configure to always stage this file upon modification so it will be saved with each `commit`?

Comment: I'm aware in theory by saving the source files one can always just build the resultant file, but this may depend on the specific system and I want to keep an immutable copy of the product in the repo just in case.

Comment: What about backported changes? Just one example of why you should stick to source.

Comment: @MadPhysicist, I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: In that case, use @hek2mgl's answer. It is probably as good as it gets for something like what you are trying to do.

Comment: Backports are when you include changes into older versions of your product. This is usually bug fixes, but can also include new features, such as the `__future__` module in Python 2. If you are not interested in doing that, there is no objection to using a pre-commit hook.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can build the "product" out of the sources in the git repository then there is no need to add it. One can simply check out the source code and build it.

If you want to do it anyway, have a look at git [*hooks*](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks). You can for example write a `pre-commit` hook that adds the file for you before each commit - automatically.

Let me add a simple example. Let's say you have a simple repo with just one file called `demo.c`. To automatically compile the program and add the binary to every commit, you can place a file called `pre-commit` into the local `.git/hooks` folder and make it executable:

*.git/hooks/pre-commit*

```
#!/bin/sh

# Compile program
gcc demo.c -o demo

# Add to index
git add demo
```

But I still think it is not the right workflow. Instead setup a build server, like [Jenkins](https://jenkins-ci.org/), in a way that it automatically builds the program once a commit has been added to git. That concept is called *continuous integration*.

Comment: Your first sentence doesn't help me.  Please see comments on the OP.

Comment: Hopefully it helps others.

Comment: @MadPhysicist, Yea, I've never understood why people on StackExchange consider a question good enough to answer but not vote on, but that's a discussion for Meta.

Comment: @user1717828 I basically answered because I wanted you and others which may find this on Google point to the fact that a source code repo usually includes all files to build a program but not the program itself. Extra for you I added a hint to git hooks which are the solution to your problem. Still there is the issue that git hooks are, 2016, a well known concept which has been explained many times on SO before.

Comment: @hek2mgl, I don't have the rep to do it, but if you could find mark my question as a duplicate of one asking about hooks I would appreciate it.

Comment: Ok, I've issued a close vote. I hope it fit's your needs and helps to solve your problem.